# Find time taken to connect to a call using AT command

Tags: call, gsm, modem, at-command

I am using a GSM modem and using minicom to pass AT commands to the modem. I need to find out the following.

1. Time taken to initiate a call.
2. Time elapsed till the user picks up the call.
3. Duration of the call.
4. Time modem takes to disconnect.

I am passing ATDT command to call from my modem.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  Can you not write code to do these things, and compare timestamps taken at the relevant points?

Comment: I am able to connect to the modems, any suggestions on what AT commands to pass?

Comment: Read 3GPP TS 27.007, the specification of standard GSM AT commands.